# Controlling a high voltage relay by a PC USB

Tags: usb, relay, high-voltage, isolation

My 2.1 speaker's transformer is consuming active power even when the PC is off. I know it because it is always warm. Thus, I want that only when my PC is operating the transformer will get the AC power from the gird. So I need to put a relay between the L1 from the grid to the correct pin in the transformer. 
I have managed to configure in my BIOS that when the PC is off the USB will not have output voltage, so I am planing to use a USB port (5V) as control pin for the relay.

I saw that there are relays which have a second level of isolation by using a LED.
Is it too dangerous to use only 1 level of isolation between my PC (USB port) to the grid? 
I mean that the 5V from USB will output the current for the relay's coil.

Thanks!

Comment: you can buy a power bar that shuts off power outlets when the control outlet stops supplying power (PC turned off)

Comment: Can you give a link to this device? I never heard about it

Comment: You can use a small 5V relay to trigger a larger 24V industrial relay if you really want that much isolation. I think the isolation that you are going to get from one small 5V relay will be plenty, relays are design for this purpose. Check digikey they have tons of relays like this.

Comment: Is it by any chance a traditional wire-wound transformer? In which case replacing it with SMPS adapter will reduce standby current to almost nothing. Having said that, the isolation provided by the relay should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I am not sure I can use SMPS because it transform from AC to AC not to DC

Comment: @Daniel_ee571 That's news to me. I didn't know that my phone runs on AC :) What are the power requirements of your speakers?

Comment: The powerbars in question don't have standard nomenclature, but you can find them by searching for "Energy saver power bar" "smart power bar" or "switching power bar".  They can be a bit touchy for really small loads but for something large like a computer they work well.  One of mine lost its extra functions and became a normal powerbar for some reason after about 3 years.  If you're going to go to the trouble of building the like yourself, the optoisolator would be worth it.

Comment: @Maple , I was not clear :)
I meant that I need an AC to AC converter and not AC to DC(like the SMPS)

Comment: @KH Thanks for the advice man :) 
The funny thing is that they don't sell this product in my country, what a waste

Comment: Ah, I see. Or rather... not. Do your speakers have build-in power supply with AC input? Why you need a transformer then? Or is it inside the speakers? Really, you need to provide more details if you expect any good advice. You actual question has been answered - relay by itself should provide enough isolation. Optocoupler is nice to have but then you need another power source for relay. That is why I am asking for more details - maybe there is better solution for this problem.

Comment: @Maple my transformer take input 230Vac 120mA and its' output is 9Vac 1200mA. All in 50Hz

Comment: OK, so, your speakers require 9VAC @ 1.2A. This is very strange power choice, but not high. Now, whatever circuitry is inside speakers, I am pretty sure it is not AC. So, somewhere inside there is  a rectifier with filter and regulator. Something like 10-12VDC. If you have an access to that, you can add standard barrel jack ($0.3) and then buy switching wall adapter for 12VDC @ 2A ($2) and be done. Or, you can buy switching module with "enable" input and control it with optocoupler, no relay necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any power relay with 5-V primary coil will do the job, providing up to 5 KV isolation between your PC and the AC mains. Example [G2R-2-DC4](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/G2R-2-DC4/G2R-2-DC4-ND/1789750):

[image]